# SQL Query to select products from all categories of One Parent

Tags: sql, parent, join

I have a Product Table with this structure

```
 id, title, slug, details, category(FK category.ID)
```

And a Category Table:
    id, name, slug, parent

Categories have only 1 level
If there is no parent then parent field is 0 else id of parent category saved

Suppose I have categories structure like this:

```
FRUITS
|---- APPLE
|---- MANGO
|---- BANANA
```

I use a Category slug to query products from a category

category.php?cat=apple
category.php?cat=mango

1st query:

```
select id,name from category WHERE slug='$catslug'
```

After getting ID of category then use query to get results of that ID from products table

```
select * from products where category=$categoryid
```

What query is required if I want to fetch all products posted in FRUITS?

```
category.php?cat=fruits
```

I want to get all products posted in apple, mango, banana (all children of fruits)

Only the child IDs are saved in product table how do I link parent category apple with these?

Comment: How many levels of categories do you have?  Ever more than 2?

Comment: Does the parent column store the parent's id or name? Which database are you using?

Comment: @mellamokb have only 1 level parent-child If category have parent then ID is saved in parent field of category table else 0 which is default

Comment: @AmitBhargava yes id of parent cat saved in parent field if no parent 0 DB type InnoDB

Answer (score 3):

You can look for categories linked to products where the parent category is the fruit category by using multiple joins.  Here `cc` refers to the child category and `cp` refers to the parent category.  We retrieve all products having a child category equal to the products category, and having a parent category to that child category equal to `FRUITS`:

```
    select *
      from products p
inner join categories cc on cc.category = p.category
inner join categories cp on cp.category = cc.parentcategory
     where cp.category = 'FRUITS'
```

If this needs to be a generic solution that handles both parent and child categories seemlessly, you can check for a match at either level (assuming all category names are unique, and every product has a category):

```
    select *
      from products p
inner join categories cc on cc.category = p.category
 left join categories cp on cp.category = cc.parentcategory
     where cc.category = '$category' or cp.category = '$category'
```

Comment: thanks for help. All Names not unique but slug & ID unique 
I think your solution is based on Category Name?
only ID is saved category.parent if no parent then 0 and in table product.category also contains category ID & every product must have 1 category.

Comment: I used 2nd query with some replacement of slug
`select * from products p 
Inner JOIN users u ON u.id = p.author   
inner join category cc on cc.id = p.category
left join category cp on cp.id = cc.parent
where cc.slug = '$catslug' or cp.slug = '$catslug' 
ORDER BY p.date DESC`

but it skips last record if Parent category fruit has 6 records it shows 5 only & skip last record which is latest entry in child from product table !
added users tables JOIN
also I want to get category.name from category table in result

Comment: yeah records problem solved with loop in body
now want to get category name[category.name] in query

Answer (score 2):

1) You don't need to use two queries, you can use join:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.slug ...
FROM products p
JOIN categories c ON c.id = p.category
WHERE c.slug = 'apple'
```

2) You can select all fruit products with this query:

```
SELECT id, title, slug ...
FROM products
WHERE category IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM categories
  WHERE slug = 'fruits'
  UNION
  SELECT c.id
  FROM categories c
  JOIN categories c2 ON c2.id = c.parent
  WHERE c2.slug = 'fruits'
)
```

Comment: I use 1st query at start of page to get catname & catid then display catname description in title & head 
Afterwards 2nd query in page with loop to list all products from that catid

only category ID is saved in category.parent 
since I use slug to get results 1st I need to match category slug with ID ?

Comment: many thanks its working perfect :)
but query toooks very long time 
1 thing more 
Can I use IF ELSE i.e. two different queries if there is no parent than normal query without UNION

Comment: are you sure that you have necessary primary/foreign keys/indexes?

Comment: yes products id,slug primary products.category FK of category.id
products.author FK of users.id
& category.id, category.slug unique

Comment: how to get name of child category(category.name) from category table in which product is posted with id of that child category(product.category) to show below product with this query

Answer (score 0):

I used 2nd query suggested by tarmaq

```
SELECT * 
    FROM products
    WHERE category IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM category
    WHERE slug = '$cats'
    UNION
    SELECT c.id
    FROM category c
    JOIN category c2 ON c2.id = c.parent
    WHERE c2.slug = '$cats')";
```

Its showing results from products table only Not getting Category Name, Category Details from category table

I tried this:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM products
    WHERE category IN (
    SELECT *
    FROM category
    WHERE slug = '$cats'
    UNION
    SELECT *
    FROM category c
    JOIN category c2 ON c2.id = c.parent
    WHERE c2.slug = '$cats')";
```

result: Error in Query.

also I want to JOIN users table in above query and to show author name(users.name) alongwith product (author id saved in product table which is FK from users table users.id is unique)

```
JOIN users on products.author = users.id
```

Where to put this Join statement in above query

**EDIT** - I joined user table with author name with this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM products
JOIN users U ON U.id = products.author
WHERE category IN (
SELECT id
FROM category
WHERE slug = '$cats'
UNION
SELECT C.id
FROM category C
JOIN category C2 ON C2.id = C.parent
WHERE C2.slug = '$cats') 
ORDER BY products.date DESC
```

now want to fetch data from category table catagory.name, category.details with this query